# Inheritance in CDM/LDM models in PowerDesigner 15.3?

Tags: inheritance, powerdesigner

I downloaded PowerDesigner 15.3's trial version, and I want to build a Logical Data Model of a database. The problem is that this database must use inheritance heavily, and I can't find a way to build an inheritance relationship... The 'Inheritance' button is in fact the only disabled button in the pallete, and I can't find a way to enable it... Did anyone else have this problem too? How can I enable it?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I can only guess that your model is using the Barker notation.

Try to select another notation in the `Tools > Model Options` dialog.

For example Choose E/R+Merise.

[image: Model Option Dialog]

Comment: That was the problem! Thank you very much!

Comment: I was struggling with this for a loooooong time!

Answer (score 0):

You'd better build a conceptual data model(CDM) first, and build the inheritance relationship in CDM.

After finished the CDM, you can select Tools>Generate Logical Data Model to genrate the LDM.

After adjust the LDM, you can select Tools>Generate Physical Data Model to genrate the PDM.

At last, select Database>Generate Database to generate SQL scripts.